# Chrome keeps loading a old cache of my website

Tags: google-chrome, caching

I am experiencing this weird issue where my Chrome browser keeps loading a old version of my website whose code doesn't even exist on my server any more. I assume it's a typical cache issue.

I tried to clean the browser cache, use igcognito mode, and clean DNS cache. The old cached page is still being loaded.

This issue seems to have been discussing on this google group for three years but there is still no solutions. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/xR-6YAkcASQ

Using firefox or any other web browsers works perfectly.

It doesn't just happen to me. All my coworkers experience the same issue on my website.

Comment: What's your question? How to fix the website from not loading as such?

Comment: yup. I want Chrome to load what is on the server

Comment: If you're using the latest Chrome and opening the website in an incognito window, Chrome doesn't even have access to its cache. You could also just completely disable the cache by opening the developer tools, open its settings (gear icon) and turning the option on. If it still happens then, it's not Chrome's cache. If it doesn't happen anymore, just remove the cache folders yourself / start a new, clean profile and session to make sure it never bumps into those orphaned files again.

Comment: test again the next day. it starts to work again. Thanks indeed for helping out. I do need to disable my cache though, thanks for sharing how to disable it.

Comment: I have same issue, it's as if you have to wait for something up the chain to clear it's cache before you see the new version.  I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: I also had this problem, I "solved it" by opening in incognito.

Comment: It's amazing that in 2020 this is still a problem.  And the standard solution is "Clear your cache". Some of us run businesses with websites and would prefer to not tell every customer to go "clear your cache" every time we make an update.  It's hideous.  The other solution of versioning every js file (smack my head) doesn't work when you are using frameworks like React.  Maybe in 20 years, this will finally be fixed by a "dirty" flag being sent from the server to the client as it should have been 20 years ago.

Comment: Yes, 2020 same problem with Angular application! It´s unbelievable.

Comment: Google is failing to tell us they store cache in our accounts.  This has happened to me for years and every time, I either A) just have to wait for whatever upstream process handles this and keep refreshing or B) log out of my Google account within Chrome and upon refresh the cache is "immediately" purged.

Comment: 2021 and still facing this issue. Despite having all meta tags in the index page, Chrome still loads the old page. Ctrl-F5 loads the latest page. But opening the page on a new tab goes back to the old version.

Comment: Yup Nov 2021 still have this issue

Comment: I still have this, even on Edge Chromium. Makes me nuts. Ctrl+F5 refresh work, but if I close and reopen, old version again !!! 2022 almos 2023!

Answer (score 16):

> ```
> <?php Header("Cache-Control: max-age=3000, must-revalidate"); ?>
> ```

You can implement a PHP script that must be the first line of code in your index file . It is an http header typically issued by web servers. You can also rename the resource that is considered "stale". This tutorial will give you more details. https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Comment: Even though we're many versions of Chrome later, this answer still fixed a problem we were having in development.  Also, just to clarify, this header can be added in any web server - it's **not** PHP specific.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but I was experiencing something similar and instead of clearing the cache I disabled it by doing this:
Open chrome and then go to your website
Press Command + Option + C(Mac)
Now that you've opened chrome's DevTools, go to the main menu where it says: Elements  Console Sources ...
Click on the menu element that says Network
Make sure that the "Disable Cache" checkbox is checked
Then reload the page without closing the DevTools
This worked for me.
Let me know if it worked for you :)

Comment: The keyboard shortcut on Windows is <CTRL><SHIFT>I
This worked for me as well

Answer (score 3):

A short term fix to view the new version of your site would normally be to clear out the cache and reload, for some reason this doesn't always work on Chrome. This short term solution is not going to fix the problem for every user that's on your site though, it will just allow you to see the new version of your site.

Adding version numbers to CSS and JS files will allow you and every other user, to see the most recent version of your site. A version number will force any browser not to load from the a user's personal computer cache, and instead load the actual files on the server, if the version number varies from the one in the user's cache.

So if you have these files on your server:

```
ExJS.js
ExCSS.css
```

and change them to:

```
ExJS.js?v=1.01
ExCSS.css?v=1.01
```

the new version of these files will load in any browser.

Normally, a browser will always load the HTML file from the server, but there are some HTML meta tags you can use to make sure that the most recent HTML version will load for any user:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

There are also ways to make sure that files in other languages always load the most recent version as well, which is discussed on this post:

[How to add version number to HTML file (not only to css and js files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855187/how-to-add-version-number-to-html-file-not-only-to-css-and-js-files/42855316)

Comment: chrome://settings/siteData to delete data from individual sites

Answer (score 1):

Adding CNAME Will help also if you always run site without www, try with [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) will work.

Answer (score 0):

change the name of images and make the necessary image name changes in html file.. found this quick fix for my website

Answer (score 0):

You can press on [Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BAEx.png), then Network and check Disable cache.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and I also tried to disable caching on my JSP pages

```
<% response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
   response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
   response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); %>
```

But it didn't help.

This is a known issue with google chrome and chromium browsers, even though you clear cache and cookie.

**However it may or may not happen for most of the users.**

Also this has been unresolved till the date since last 9-10 years.

Hence for testing purposes I would highly recommend to use Mozilla Firefox or Opera.

However it does sounds that your application is limited to certain browsers for best experience, and may not sound convincing to Business/End users.

But having said that, **this caching issue may or may not happen to most of us.**

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to clear the problem by resetting Chrome. This is the only way I found to clear this condition - after tearing my hair out for half a day.

Prior to finding this, I tried clearing the cache, deleting the contents of the various cache directories etc. in vain.

[As of today May 3 2021] You can do this by gong to 'Settings > Advanced > Reset and clean up > Restore settings to their original defaults'. Note that this will not remove any bookmarks but will log you out of all accounts you are signed into.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue developing locally, and tried the following things:

1. Clearing Cache + generally ALL files in Chrome
2. Setting the Cache-Control Header like Eli Duhon mentioned.
3. Setting the Cache Control Header in multiple other ways.

And the only thing that fixed the problem for me was to basically re-start my docker containers on which the app was running.

so I did this:

> `docker-compose down`

And then

> `docker-compose up`

and everything was updated after that.

**HOWEVER, if you have changes again, they are still not updated...**

So this is certainly not a fix to this problem, as I dont even know what causes this behaviour in the first place, but I assume it has to do something with hot reloading and/or Docker but that was the only thing that did the trick for me so I thought I would mention it here...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem moving a Wordpress site to new hosting where the URL redirects to .../wp, which hadn't been the case before.

Chrome was helpfully presenting a directory listing showing the file dates from the old server, despite the DNS having updated fully a week ago. So it was obviously demonstrating the problem discussed here.

I added an index.html file with just the following in it:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://my-wp-site.com/wp'"/>
```

which fixed the problem straight away, including on Chrome browsers that had not had their cache cleared and that had no knowledge of any Google account of mine.

I don't know why this worked, however, given all the problems people have listed above.

Answer (score -2):

you have two options

a) consider fingerprint the stale resources like

```
 <script src="js/app-4829382839238882882bb3442bbbbdhh3kh3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

b) Add cache control headers such as Cache-Control, Expires on your webserver.

This is a good read on [browser caching](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching)

Comment: Please explain your answer further. And the link you provided is obsolete.