# How to add version number to HTML file (not only to css and js files)

Tags: javascript, html, css, caching, version

Many people use version numbers on css and js files to force non-cached versions to load up on webpages when updates are published:

CSS example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?v=2017-03-17">
```

JS example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js?v=2017-03-17"></script>
```

I've noticed that by adding version numbers to css/js files, the web browsers will also load up the **HTML file** (from which the css/js files are referenced from) from scratch and not use the cached version.

Is this a sufficient way of ensuring that HTML-files are displayed from scratch in all web browsers, or is there a way to set a version number to the **HTML file** as well, to ensure newly updated HTML-documents are not loaded from a browser's cache?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Usually the browser takes always the newer version of your HTML.

If you wish to prevent any cache you can use those tricks:

> The correct minimum set of headers that works across the most
>   important browsers:
>
> ```
> Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
> Pragma: no-cache
> Expires: 0
> ```
>
> HTML
>
> ```
> <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
> <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
> <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
> ```
>
> .htaccess (Apache)
>
> ```
> <IfModule mod_headers.c>
>   Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
>   Header set Pragma "no-cache"
>   Header set Expires 0
> </IfModule>
> ```
>
> Java Servlet
>
> ```
> response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
> response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
> response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
> ```
>
> PHP
>
> ```
> header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
> header('Pragma: no-cache');
> header('Expires: 0');
> ```
>
> ASP
>
> ```
> Response.addHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
> Response.addHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
> Response.addHeader "Expires", "0"
> ```
>
> ASP.NET
>
> ```
> Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
> Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
> Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "0");
> ```
>
> Ruby on Rails
>
> ```
> response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
> response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
> response.headers['Expires'] = '0'
> ```
>
> Python on Flask
>
> ```
> resp.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
> resp.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
> resp.headers["Expires"] = "0"
> ```
>
> Google Go
>
> ```
> responseWriter.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
> responseWriter.Header().Set("Pragma", "no-cache")
> responseWriter.Header().Set("Expires", "0")
> ```

source: http://cristian.sulea.net/blog.php?p=2014-01-14-disable-browser-caching-with-meta-html-tags

Comment: What do you do to bust a cache that was created when the file served did not have these headers?